# Paypal asks my users to directly pay with credit/debit cards

Tags: paypal

I want flow the way as when my users click on pay button they will be direcly redirected to credit/debit card details page. Paypal should not ask for login page first. Here I'm attaching the snapshot for your reference purpose..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8J3D.png)

Answer (score 0):

To have a 'Debit or Credit Card' checkout option, integrate the latest [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).

It doesn't even redirect away from your website, which is highly desirable for conversion / reducing buyer friction and not presenting them with a new, unfamiliar web page if they haven't used PayPal before.